# How to input data into data frame using nested for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe

Using the following code, I can print the values iterating each for loop.

```
for(i in 5:12)
{
  for(j in 5:12)
  {
    for(k in 5:12)
    {
      for(l in 5:12)
      {
        cat(i,j,k,l,'\n')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to store the output data into a data frame df considering 4 columns (a,b,c,d) of numeric data. All I know is only the following code but has only single 'for' in it.

```
f3 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(n), y = numeric(n))
  for(i in 1:n){
    df$x[i] <- i
    df$y[i] <- i
  }
  df
}
```

How to input data into data frames while using nested for loops. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `expand.grid`

```
a <- 5:12
df <- expand.grid(a,a,a,a)
names(df) <- c("a","b","c","d")
```